# Why do SetWindowLongW and GetWindowLongW strip pointers' first 2 digits?

Tags: winapi, rust

I am trying to make [application state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-) working in Rust.

I got the Rust application state part from [windows-rs sample line 357](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/samples/direct2d/src/main.rs) and modified it a little to work with my code. The only problem is, it did not work as expected...

As you can see from the comments in the code below, my problem is that after using the mentioned two functions my pointer (`state`) loses its first two digits.

Every time I run this, the first two digits are always missing.

How can I solve this?

```rust
extern "system" fn wndproc(window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match message as u32 {
            WM_NCCREATE => {
                // ORIGINAL address given to CreateWindowExW: 0xb678ddf730
                let cs = lparam as *const CREATESTRUCTW;
                let state = (*cs).lpCreateParams as *mut State;
                
                println!("{:?}", state); // OUTPUT: 0xb678ddf730 (correct)

                // After using the two functions:
                SetWindowLongW(window, GWLP_USERDATA, state as i32);

                let state = GetWindowLongW(window, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut State;

                println!("{:?}", state); // OUTPUT: 0x78ddf730 (missing first 2 digits "b6")
                1
            }
            ...
```

Full code:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]
//#![allow(unused_)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use windows_sys::{
    Win32::Foundation::*,
    Win32::Graphics::Gdi::ValidateRect,
    Win32::System::LibraryLoader::GetModuleHandleW,
    Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*,
};

fn u16_str(string: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    let mut result: Vec<u16> = string.encode_utf16().collect();
    result.push(0);
    result
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct State {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let instance = GetModuleHandleW(std::ptr::null());

        let wc = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(0, IDC_ARROW),
            hInstance: instance,
            lpszClassName: u16_str("asd").as_ptr(),
            style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(wndproc),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hIcon: 0,
            hbrBackground: 0,
            lpszMenuName: std::ptr::null(),
            hIconSm: 0,
        };

        RegisterClassExW(&wc);

        let mut state = State {
            name: String::from("name"),
        };

        println!("{:?}", &mut state as *mut _);

        CreateWindowExW(
            0,
            u16_str("asd").as_ptr(),
            u16_str("Ablak 1 áéőüűö").as_ptr(),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 0, instance, &mut state as *mut _ as _,
        );

        let mut message = std::mem::zeroed();

        while GetMessageW(&mut message, 0, 0, 0) != 0 {
            DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }
    }
}

extern "system" fn wndproc(window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match message as u32 {
            WM_NCCREATE => {
                let cs = lparam as *const CREATESTRUCTW;
                let state = (*cs).lpCreateParams as *mut State;

                println!("{:?}", state);

                SetWindowLongW(window, GWLP_USERDATA, state as i32);

                let state = GetWindowLongW(window, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut State;

                println!("{:?}", state);
                1
            }
            WM_PAINT => {
                //let state = GetWindowLongPtrW(window, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut State;
                //println!("{:?}", state);
                //println!("{}", GetLastError());
                println!("paint");
                ValidateRect(window, std::ptr::null());
                0
            }
            WM_DESTROY => {
                println!("WM_DESTROY");
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                0
            }
            _ => DefWindowProcW(window, message, wparam, lparam),
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
...

[dependencies.windows-sys]
version = "0.36.1"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_LibraryLoader",
    "Win32_Graphics_Gdi",
    "Win32_Graphics_Direct2D",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
]
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`GetWindowLongW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongw) and [`SetWindowLongW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongw) API calls can only store 32-bit values. 32 bits is the size of a pointer for 32-bit architectures. Since you are targeting a 64-bit architecture, you'll have to follow the advice from the documentation:

> If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle, this function has been superseded by the [`GetWindowLongPtrW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw) function. (Pointers and handles are 32 bits on 32-bit Windows and 64 bits on 64-bit Windows.) To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use `GetWindowLongPtrW`.

and

> This function has been superseded by the [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) function. To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use the `SetWindowLongPtr` function.

You'll have to replace

```rust
SetWindowLongW(window, GWLP_USERDATA, state as i32);
//                                          ^^^^^^ truncates pointer to 32 bits
```

with

```rust
SetWindowLongPtrW(window, GWLP_USERDATA, state as isize);
```

The `GetWindowLongW` calls merely need to be replaced with `GetWindowLongPtrW` calls. Other changes aren't required here.

Note that while the `-Ptr` variants are immediately available through the *windows* and *windows-sys* crates when targeting a 64-bit architecture, they are missing for 32-bit targets (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/1493)). You can provide your own implementation, e.g.

```rust
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
unsafe fn SetWindowLongPtrW(window: HWND, index: WINDOW_LONG_PTR_INDEX, value: isize) -> isize {
    SetWindowLongW(window, index, value as _) as _
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
unsafe fn GetWindowLongPtrW(window: HWND, index: WINDOW_LONG_PTR_INDEX) -> isize {
    GetWindowLongA(window, index) as _
}
```

With that in place you can simply call `GetWindowLongPtrW`/`SetWindowLongPtrW` irrespective of target architecture, same as when writing C/C++ code using the Windows SDK headers.